# i want to make an slide div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am in trouble, i have a `DIV` PA in my web and i need to display on it (not at same time!) 3 pics, i have this code but for some reason it is not displaying the images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgs = ['Imagenes/1.jpg', 'Imagenes/2.jpg', 'Imagenes/3.jpg'];
    var cnt = imgs.length;

    $(function() {
        setInterval(Slider, 3000);
    });

    function Slider() {
    $('#apDiv2').fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    }
```

and

```
<div id="apDiv2"> </div>
```

Thank you in advance!
Regards.

**Edited: I found the code i searched, thank to those that gave me tips, my regards**

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var now = 0;
    var int = self.setInterval("changeBG()", 3000);
    var array = ["Imagenes/1.jpg", "Imagenes/2.jpg", "Imagenes/3.jpg", ];

    function changeBG(){
        //array of backgrounds
        now = (now+1) % array.length ;
        $('#apDiv2').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: I suspect that `src` is not a valid attribute on `<div>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `#apDiv2` isn't an `img` in , then setting it's `src` attribute won't do anything. So consider changing to this:

```
<img id="apDiv2" src="" alt="" />
```

Comment: it works but i want to do it with DIV, i tested a code once but i can't find it. Thank you.

Comment: @user3433247 you can do with div then have to use css background property for that...

Answer (score 0):

src attribute is not avalable in `div` so you can use inside `div` `img` tage and set that attribute.

```
<img id="apDiv2" src=""/>
```

if you set the background of div that can also another way.